# PHP $_SERVER['HOST_NAME'] return ELB address with AWS ELB + EC2

Tags: php, joomla, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I am using AWS CloudFront -> ELB -> 2 x EC2 instance and I have setup pointed my domain www.mydomain.net to the domain of CF.  CF will cache the returns of ELB.  ELB connected to 2 EC2 instance (Web1 and Web2).

I have a PHP script that use `$_SERVER['HOST_NAME']`, but it doesn't return `www.mydomain.net`, it returns the ELB domain name.

How can I set it return www.mydomain.net?

Comment: Am I correct that you do not want to set `$_SERVER['HOST_NAME']` yourself but instead read from it, just looking for the different hostname?

Comment: Like this? http://serverfault.com/questions/187535/detect-server-name-in-php

Comment: My site is running Joomla, and it is very depends on the $_SERVER['HOST_NAME'] value.  And I wish this value returns "www.mydomain.net", however it is now the elb domain.

Comment: In your bootstrapping process you can set `$_SERVER['HOST_NAME']` to any value you love and like. Joomla will use it then.

Comment: You may want to set the live_site variable in your configuration.php.

Comment: At the end, I used the below apache setting:
`<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/html"
    ServerName www.mydomain.net
    ServerAlias xxxxxxxx.elb.amazonaws.com
    ErrorLog "logs/www.domain.net-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/www.domain.net-access.log" common
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxxxxxxx.elb.amazonaws.com [NC]
        RewriteRule ^ - [E=rewritten:3]
        RequestHeader set Host www.mydomain.net
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: and add these 2 lines in index.php
`$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = 'www.mydomain.net';`
`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'www.mydomain.net';`

Answer (score 2):

In CloudFront, you will need to forward the 'Host' header to the origin (Whitelist the 'Host' header). By default "CloudFront sets the value to the domain name of the origin that is associated with the requested object" ~ http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#request-custom-headers-behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue with a wordpress multisite installation.
I have this small 'if' condition in wp-config for the fix:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'])) {  
        $list = explode(',',$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST']);
        $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = $list[0];
        $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']=$list[0];
  }
```